# Integral which needs absolute value of zero

Tags: integration, absolute-value

I'm trying to solve an integral $$\int_0^t dx \,e^{-\nu \,|x-t|}$$
The trouble I'm having is that in the final stages this seems to need me to have a value for $\frac{0}{|0|}$, which I don't think is defined. My solution looks like this:
First, we sub in $u = x-t, \,\,du = dx$:
\begin{align}
 \int_0^{t'} du \,e^{-\nu \,|u|}\\
\end{align}
Where $t'$ indicates that the new limit.
Then we re-write the integral as
$$\frac{|u|}{u}\int_0^t\frac{u}{|u|}e^{-\nu|u|}$$
Make another substitution $v = |u|,\,\,dv = \frac{|u|}{u}du$ to give 
\begin{align}
&\quad \frac{|u|}{u}\int_0^{t''}\frac{u}{|u|}\frac{|u|}{u}e^{-\nu\,v}dv\\
&=\frac{|u|}{u}\int_0^{t''}e^{-\nu\, v}dv\\
&=\frac{|u|}{u}\cdot \frac{-1}{\nu}e^{-\nu\,v}\bigg|_0^{t''}\\
& = -\frac{|x-t|}{x-t}\frac{1}{\nu}e^{-\nu\,|x-t|}\bigg|_0^t
\end{align}
Putting the limits in, we get
\begin{align}I &= \frac{1}{\nu}\left(-\frac{|t-t|}{t-t}e^{-\nu\,|t-t|}- \frac{|0-t|}{0-t}e^{-\nu\,|0-t|}  \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\nu}\left(   -\frac{|0|}{0}-e^{-\nu t}\right)
\end{align}
where in the final step I have assumed that $t>0$. 
What am I missing?

Comment: If you stop and think at the beginning you'll rewrite your integral immediately as $\displaystyle\int_0^t e^{-\nu u}\,du$, using $u=t-x$.

Comment: "$\begin{align}
 \int_0^{t'} du \,e^{-\nu \,|u|}\\
\end{align}$ where t' is the new limit".  That's the new top limit.  What about the new  *bottom* limit?  It should be "\begin{align}
 \int_{0'}^{t'} du \,e^{-\nu \,|u|}\\
\end{align}"  and why bother with these t' and 0'?  as we have u = x -t let's just substitute x - t : "$\begin{align}
 \int_{0-t=-t}^{t-t = 0} du \,e^{-\nu \,|u|}\\
\end{align}$"  I hope it is now obvious where you went wrong.